# How can I mock a Net::HTTP.open to a URL in RSPEC

Tags: rspec

This is my code that I want to mock in RSPEC

```
  url = "http://www.somewebsite.com"
  html = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)
  html.search('div.yty_bar').remove
```

I have seen other examples releated to my question but they dont seem to help.

Thanks

Comment: is there no answer to my question?

Answer (score 3):

Use the webmock gem - https://github.com/bblimke/webmock